# Do React state updates occur in order when used like an FSM and useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to build a simple FSM (finite state machine) in ReactJS functional components.  I am looking [at this](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) which specifies that they it can do it asynchronously and second they may merge the state changes.

In class components, you can chain state changes using the two-argument `setState()` method.  But that capability is not available in the `useState()` hook.

Basically I am wondering because of the behaviour specified is it possible to create an FSM?  I am trying to trim the example as small as I can

I am making a few restrictions on my usage of the setter, namely it will only be executed in:

- a state handler function
- an event handler (and even this is limitted)
- a state can have its own substate which is another state store (basically additional parameters that may only be read or written by the two above functions)

Anyway I set my initial state and I have a single `useEffect` hook for the state as follows

```js
const [fsmState, setFsmState] = useState(States.Initial)
useEffect(() => {
  stateHandlers[fsmState]();
}, [fsmState]);
```

`States` is an `enum`

```js
enum States {
  Initial,
  Unauthenticated,
  Authenticated,
  Processing
}
```

I define `stateHandlers` as follows:

```
  const stateHandlers: {
    [key in States]: () => void | Promise<void>;
  } = {
    [States.Initial]: async () => { 
      // this may load authentication state from a store, 
      // for now just set it to Unauthenticated
      setFsmState(State.Unauthenticated);
    },
    [States.SigningIn]: async () => { 
      const authToken = await loginToServer(signInState));
      if (authToken.isValid()) {
        setFsmState(State.Authenticated);
      } else {
        setFsmState(State.Unauthenticated);
      }
    },
    [States.Authenticated]: () => { },
    [States.Unauthenticated]: () => { },
  }
```

For the event handler e.g. sign in I do this (which is basically the reason I am asking the question.

```
const signinAsync = async (username: string, password: string) => {
  if (fsmState !== States.Unauthenticated) throw Error("invalid state");
  // would these two get set in order?
  setSignInState({username,password})
  setFsmState(State.SigningIn);
}
```

As specified earlier, the two-argument version is not available so I cannot do

```
setSignInState({username,password},
  () => { setFsmState(State.SigningIn) } )
```

I just wanted a simple TSX implementation to avoid adding additional libraries.  However, I am still in the midst of coding this as I learn TypeScript/React.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. In fact,there is a well known FMS library called xstate https://github.com/davidkpiano/xstate.

Updating state will always be asynchronous because that is how it works and rightly so. In your state machine handler, you just need to make sure that the transition is correct. I can already see that your implementation is already heading to the right direction.

```
const signinAsync = async (username: string, password: string) => {
  if (fsmState !== States.Unauthenticated) throw Error("invalid state");
  // would these two get set in order?
  setSignInState({username,password})
  setFsmState(State.SigningIn);
}
```

There is no guarantee which one will happen first. Your implementation should handle all cases, whether setSignInState or setFsmState happens first. Both actions should be independent. If you need both to be in a series then you need to chain them in a callback or something. For example, with setState you can pass a second arguments as a callback that will be called after state is updated.

```
this.setState({ title: event.target.value }, function() {
    this.validateTitle(); // thid will happen after state update
  });
```

Comment: can setState be followed by another setState?,  I just tried does not appear to work with hooks     
setSignInState({ username, password, serverUri }, ()=>{
      setAuthState(AuthStates.SigningIn);
    });

Comment: apparently the 2nd argument does not exist for setState with hook. You will need to use setState from Class Component. I'm not sure what does this function setSignInState do but maybe you can call setAuthState inside there instead

Comment: but how would you get the "setState" function from a functional component?  Maybe that could be another question.

Comment: Actually I can update my question to ask that

Comment: Unfortunately it's not available in a functional component. I see that your stateHandlers depends on signInState which is located in the outside. That is an anti pattern. Your stateHandlers should be pure, which means it should not depend on any external variables. I'd recommend u to add 2nd argument in the stateHandler as extra data and call it like this `setFsmState(State.SigningIn, { username , password });`

Comment: setFsmState is provided by the useState hook though, and it does not accept a second parameter..  I actually changed my code slightly so the "signInState" is useRef rather than useState since it shouldn't trigger a re-render